# emacs compile buffer auto close?

Tags: emacs, buffer, compile-mode

I want to auto close the compile buffer when there is no error and no warning,but i want to show it when there is warnings. Anyone can help me? This code from [emacswiki](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeCompile#toc2) only do the first requirement. How to change it?

```
  ;; Helper for compilation. Close the compilation window if
  ;; there was no error at all.
  (defun compilation-exit-autoclose (status code msg)
    ;; If M-x compile exists with a 0
    (when (and (eq status 'exit) (zerop code))
      ;; then bury the *compilation* buffer, so that C-x b doesn't go there
      (bury-buffer)
      ;; and delete the *compilation* window
      (delete-window (get-buffer-window (get-buffer "*compilation*"))))
    ;; Always return the anticipated result of compilation-exit-message-function
    (cons msg code))
  ;; Specify my function (maybe I should have done a lambda function)
  (setq compilation-exit-message-function 'compilation-exit-autoclose)
```

Comment: @Thomas this isn't the key problem

Comment: It might be useful to know which compiler you're running because you might be able to use the `msg` parameter to check if there are errors or warnings.

Comment: You could try adding another condition to the and clause to look for the string 'warning' in the **compilation** buffer.  Or whatever other string that your compiler uses to indicate warnings.

Comment: @vpit3833 i just tried it , but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I use the following for compilation.  It keeps the compilation buffer if there are warnings or errors, and buries it otherwise (after 1 second).

```
(defun bury-compile-buffer-if-successful (buffer string)
 "Bury a compilation buffer if succeeded without warnings "
 (when (and
         (buffer-live-p buffer)
         (string-match "compilation" (buffer-name buffer))
         (string-match "finished" string)
         (not
          (with-current-buffer buffer
            (goto-char (point-min))
            (search-forward "warning" nil t))))
    (run-with-timer 1 nil
                    (lambda (buf)
                      (bury-buffer buf)
                      (switch-to-prev-buffer (get-buffer-window buf) 'kill))
                    buffer)))
(add-hook 'compilation-finish-functions 'bury-compile-buffer-if-successful)
```

Comment: this is cool, but why does it leave the window open after the compilation buffer closes? this window then remains open until I move the cursor, then it suddenly closes. what causes this behavior?

Comment: @johnbakers: Because all it does is switch the buffer in the window, leaving the window layout unchanged.  I generally don't like Emacs to change my window layout.  Try playing with `delete-windows-on` instead of `switch-to-prev-buffer`.

Comment: this is a really neat function, but I'm wondering if I can make it always popup the compilation in a specific window rather than it automatically creating a new window at the bottom of my screen?

Comment: @johnbakers: The code in my answer doesn't pop up the window or create the buffer, that's done by `compile`; my code is run once the compilation finishes (which should be pretty obvious because it's added to `compilation-finish-functions`).  If you want more control over how the window is created, look into the `shackle` package.

Answer (score 2):

jpkotta, it does work most of the times. Sometimes, even if there is a warning, it doesn't switch to compilation buffer. So I made a change to your form & it does work now:

```
(defun bury-compile-buffer-if-successful (buffer string)
  "Bury a compilation buffer if succeeded without warnings "
  (if (and
       (string-match "compilation" (buffer-name buffer))
       (string-match "finished" string)
       (not
        (with-current-buffer buffer
          **(goto-char 1)**
          (search-forward "warning" nil t))))
      (run-with-timer 1 nil
                      (lambda (buf)
                        (bury-buffer buf)
                        (switch-to-prev-buffer (get-buffer-window buf) 'kill))
                      buffer)))
(add-hook 'compilation-finish-functions 'bury-compile-buffer-if-successful)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tweaked above answers with better logic and tested it, working perfectly:

1. Add Hooks to functions:

```
  (add-hook 'compilation-start-hook 'compilation-started)
  (add-hook 'compilation-finish-functions 'hide-compile-buffer-if-successful)
```

2. Auto Hide Compile Buffer Delay Customizable Variable (via `M-x customize-variable RET auto-hide-compile-buffer-delay`):

```
  (defcustom auto-hide-compile-buffer-delay 0
    "Time in seconds before auto hiding compile buffer."
    :group 'compilation
    :type 'number
  )
```

3. Get time taken in compilation and use `compilation-num-*` for warnings and errors count in compilation buffer:

```
  (defun hide-compile-buffer-if-successful (buffer string)
    (setq compilation-total-time (time-subtract nil compilation-start-time))
    (setq time-str (concat " (Time: " (format-time-string "%s.%3N" compilation-total-time) "s)"))

    (if
      (with-current-buffer buffer
        (setq warnings (eval compilation-num-warnings-found))
        (setq warnings-str (concat " (Warnings: " (number-to-string warnings) ")"))
        (setq errors (eval compilation-num-errors-found))

        (if (eq errors 0) nil t)
      )

      ;;If Errors then
      (message (concat "Compiled with Errors" warnings-str time-str))

      ;;If Compiled Successfully or with Warnings then
      (progn
        (bury-buffer buffer)
        (run-with-timer auto-hide-compile-buffer-delay nil 'delete-window (get-buffer-window buffer 'visible))
        (message (concat "Compiled Successfully" warnings-str time-str))
      )
    )
  )

  (make-variable-buffer-local 'compilation-start-time)

  (defun compilation-started (proc) 
    (setq compilation-start-time (current-time))
  )
```

[Demo](https://i.ibb.co/nBccFfv/hide-compile-buffer-optimized.gif)