# Return Emacs buffer focus to R after compiling with knitr

Tags: r, emacs, knitr, ess

When compiling an *.Rnw file with the commands `M-n r` and `M-n P` my open R buffer is swapped for a buffer that appears to shows knitr compilation information. Is there a way to automatically switch back to the R buffer if knitr compiles without any errors?

Comment: You may find this question useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043004/emacs-compile-buffer-auto-close

Answer (score 1):

Well the easiest way is to [advice](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) the function. An advice is a way the add something at the beginning, end (or both) of the function.

Now, I don't know which function takes care of compilation in r-mode, but assuming it is foo

```
(defadvice foo (after foo-advice () activate)
(other-window 1))
```

You just have to add an if expression to check if the compilation was error free.