# Don't display *compilation* buffer in Emacs until the process exits with error or warning

Tags: emacs, process, buffer, elisp, compile-mode

I am looking for a way to have the Emacs *compilation* buffer triggered by M-x compile, M-x recompile or some compile on save script only appear when the compilation exits either with an error or a warning.

Note that I am not looking for a way to close the compile buffer if there are no errors or warnings as described in [1]. No I want the buffer to never appear until the compilation is fully finished and only appear if there is an error or warning to display.

The reasons are simple: The flickering compile buffer is disturbing and rearranges the position of the code on the screen. This becomes more annoying if you have compile on save turned on.

The *compile* buffer contains many different types of compile processes from make to pdflatex so it would be great if the function which determines whether the buffer should be displayed works across the board.

[1] [emacs compile buffer auto close?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043004/emacs-compile-buffer-auto-close)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you can achieve what you want through temporarily disabling `display-buffer` across `compilation-start`.

This is a combination of what sds said and something posted on the comments @ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309769/how-can-i-prevent-emacs-from-opening-new-window-for-compilation-output)

The comment there had a nasty problem with point jumping in the original source buffer that I appear to have worked out by also blocking `set-window-point` and `goto-char`.  It feels like a dirty hack, but is working so far.  YMMV!

```lisp
(defun brian-compile-finish (buffer outstr)
  (unless (string-match "finished" outstr)
    (switch-to-buffer-other-window buffer))
  t)

(setq compilation-finish-functions 'brian-compile-finish)

(require 'cl)

(defadvice compilation-start
  (around inhibit-display
      (command &optional mode name-function highlight-regexp)) 
  (if (not (string-match "^\\(find\\|grep\\)" command))
      (flet ((display-buffer)
         (set-window-point)
         (goto-char)) 
    (fset 'display-buffer 'ignore)
    (fset 'goto-char 'ignore)
    (fset 'set-window-point 'ignore)
    (save-window-excursion 
      ad-do-it))
    ad-do-it))

(ad-activate 'compilation-start)
```

Now you should see that all compile buffers will only be shown if `outstr` doesn't return a successful finish status OR the invoked command started with "find" or "grep."

Comment: Using the above code and compiling results in an error: compilation-start: Wrong number of arguments: set-window-point, 0. inhidbit-display seems to be a typo but changing that doesn't fix the error.

Comment: @Rovanion I can't reproduce here (emacs v24.2.50.x) - can you get a full backtrace?  Typo fixed - but it's just a name describing what the  advice does.

Comment: @Rovanion from emacs -Q, all i had to do was `(require 'cl)` before running the code above and invoking `compile`

Comment: It seems it was the fault of something I had when I tried to use your code. Working well now.

Comment: `flet` has been deprecated (thought still worked in emacs 24.1). `cl-flet` is specifically *not* a replacement for this usage. `noflet` appears to be. See the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I edited @assem's answer to use `cl-letf` instead of `flet`.

```lisp
(defun brian-compile-finish (buffer outstr)
  (unless (string-match "finished" outstr)
    (switch-to-buffer-other-window buffer))
  t)

(setq compilation-finish-functions 'brian-compile-finish)

(defadvice compilation-start
  (around inhibit-display
      (command &optional mode name-function highlight-regexp))
  (if (not (string-match "^\\(find\\|grep\\)" command))
      (cl-letf ((display-buffer   #'ignore)
                (set-window-point #'ignoreco)
                (goto-char        #'ignore))
        (save-window-excursion
          ad-do-it))
    ad-do-it))

(ad-activate 'compilation-start)

(provide 'only-display-compile-on-error)
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `compilation-start` calls `display-buffer` on the compilation buffer. This should give you all the control you need.

I.e., you need to customize one of the *action* variables (`display-buffer-overriding-action` et al) so that it will handle compilation buffers specially buy displaying it in a separate frame and *not* displaying the frame itself.

Then you need to customize your `compilation-filter-hook` so that, whenever a warning or an error is inserted into the compilation buffer, the compilation buffer is displayed visibly (e.g., by popping up the aforementioned separate frame). Don't forget to bind your *action* variable to `nil` there!

Answer (score 1):

**assems** answer has been overtaken by events, somewhat.

Emacs core, in their wisdom have decided to deprecate `flet`. 
The suggested alternative is `cl-flet`. However, as discussed in this post, this seems to be lexically scoped rather than dynamically scoped. We explicitly want dynamic scoping.

[Should `flet` be replaced with `cl-flet` or `cl-letf` ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895605/should-flet-be-replaced-with-cl-flet-or-cl-letf#18895704)

This page suggests replace `flet` to `noflet`, a third-party library.

This appears to only support the definition of functions and their bodies.
So the `flet` in assem's answer becomes

`(noflet ((display-buffer ()) ....`

Comment: The modern replacement for `flet` is `(cl-letf (((symbol-function #'whatever) (lambda (...)))) ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

The following displays the compilation buffer only on errors. If the buffer is displayed and a new compilation completes without errors, the buffer will disappear.

```
;; Prevent the compilation buffer from being displayed until the compilation
;; process has finished. After that, ensure that this buffer is visible if and
;; only if the compilation failed.

;; (compile.el displays the buffer with (allow-no-window . t))
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
             '("\\*compilation\\*" (display-buffer-no-window)))
;; After the compilation process is finished:
(setq compilation-exit-message-function
      (lambda (status code msg)
        (let ((compilation-window
               (get-buffer-window "*compilation*")))
          (cond
           ;; If compilation failed and compilation buffer is not visible,
           ((and (eq status 'exit)
                 (not (zerop code))
                 (not compilation-window))
            ;; temporarily allow displaying the buffer,
            (let ((display-buffer-overriding-action
                   '((display-buffer-use-least-recent-window))))
              ;; and display that buffer.
              (display-buffer "*compilation*")))
           ;; If compilation succeeded and compilation buffer is visible,
           ((and (eq status 'exit)
                 (zerop code)
                 compilation-window)
            ;; bury that buffer.
            (with-selected-window compilation-window
              (bury-buffer)))))
        (cons msg code))) ;; default return value
```

Comment: I really like that addition, sweet!